# Active Record Find Records from Hash Values wrapped in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Rails and I want to make a query. I think I'm just having a brain fart, but maybe not. I have a data that's coming into my controller like follows.

```
units = [
  {:name=>"barbarian", :level=>5, :count=>10},
  {:name=>"archer", :level=>6, :count=>10}
]
```

I have a model with data corresponding data to the `name` and `level`. I want to create a query like the following...

```
Unit.where('name = ? AND level = ? OR name = ? AND level = ?', "barbarian", 5, "archer", 6)
```

Which would yield two records from the `Unit` model. But I just want to be a lot smarter about it because I'll have around 30 items in the `units` array. Is this possible? If not, what other options exist?

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like this

```
clause = units.map { 'name = ? AND level = ?' }.join(' OR ')
values = units.map {|unit| [unit[:name], unit[:level]] }
conditions = [clause, values].flatten
# => ["name = ? AND level = ? OR name = ? AND level = ?", "barbarian", 5, "archer", 6]
```

and now you can use the query like this

```
Unit.where(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try going through the hash input the making the query like this:

```
conditions = units.map do |unit_params|
  condition = unit_params.map do |k, v|
    "#{k} = '#{v}'" if k != :count
  end.compact.join(' AND ')
  "(#{condition})"
end.join(' OR ')

# conditions = "(name = 'barbarian' AND level = '5') OR (name = 'archer' AND level = '6')"

Unit.where(conditions)
```